# File injection with gulp, pick only some files from folder

Tags: gulp

I use Gulp for injecting my js files into index.html. I have the following structure of my js resources:

```
js
|-ace-builds
  |-src
    |-ace.js
    |-ext-beautify.js
    |-ext-chromevox.js
    |-ext-elastic_tabstops_lite.js
    |-...
|-angular
  |-angular.js
|-angular-ui-ace
  |-ui-ace.js
|-...
```

The problem is that from the whole **ace-builds** folder I need to inject only one file **ace.js**. Of course, one of the possible solution is to list all injected files manually, but I would like to make the injector definition quite compact and flexible.

**Questions is**: is it possible with gulp to make such file injection, ingoring other files in the folder and if yes, how?

I tried the following code, also placing the lines (1) and (2) in reverse order, but it has not worked, the ace.js is not included.

```
gulp.task('index', function () {
    var target = gulp.src('./app/html/index.html');
    var sources = gulp.src([
        'app/js/*.js',
        '!app/js/ace-builds/**/*',                 // (1)
        'app/js/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js'  // (2)
    ], { read: false });
    return target.pipe(inject(sources))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your gulp.src's actually reads the folder that ace.js is in.  Why not just include app/js/**/ace.js?  With no negation.  And, by the way, the negation will always be performed last no matter where you have it listed.  That is why you never pick up ace.js.